# JQM: centre/align icon

Tags: jquery, button, icons, size, location

I need a 200px x 200px button size, the icon in the centre (horizontal and vertical).
I can create the 200px x 200px size and I use my personal icons.

[image]

My questions is:!

- how do I centre the icon horizontally and vertically in the button?

If anyone can help me out I would really appreciate it.

Cheers,

Timo

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a{
    line-height: 600px; 
   }
-->   
        </style>
   </head>
  <body>
<a data-corners="false" href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="customized"
          data-iconpos="top" id="start-button"
          data-theme="a">LIVINGROOM</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Question remains, how to centre the icon horizontally and vertically. Or how to position the icon at all....

Comment: <style type="text/css">
<!--
.ui-icon-green5{
background-image: url(green_05_64x64.png);
}
.ui-icon {
background-color: transparent;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:150px;
}
--></style>